# How to format integer with leading and end zeros?

Tags: java, android

How can i format integer that should have a format of 0000, when the integer is 5 the formatted value should return 0500, when the integer is 10 it should return 1000 and so on.

I was trying with `String.format("%04d", int)` but i formatted value of 5 will become 0005 instead of 0500...

Comment: `String.format("%02d00", value)` or `String.format("%04d", value * 100)`

Comment: Err, decimal 5 is 5. Not 500. 5 with leading zeros is 0005. So: not sure what you are asking for.

Comment: @GhostCat It's a probably a dollars/cents monetary value without decimal point (or in cents, however you want to look at it). If you can only do whole dollars, then having dollars as an `int` makes sense, even if formatted value has to be in cents.

Comment: @Andreas +1 for the "%02d00", that what i was looking for

Comment: @KasperJuner What are you *really* up to? It looks like some monetary format. Your question sounds like a typical x-y problem. Have you considered `BigDecimal`? (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Comment: @GhostCat Doesn't have to. The question is quite clear about the desired functionality. "Why" is really immaterial.